# What would be your minimalistic wish list for new TeX programming primitives?

Tags: tex-core

I have written a lot of 'weird' TeX over the years and have never encountered a situation where TeX's
programming environment was completely inadequate. I have, however, often wished for just *a little* 
more help when writing complicated macros. Discovering juggling braces, conditionals and 
`\string`, as well as the `\romannumeral-1...` trick was fun but felt a bit too idiosyncratic. Now (only 
a month ago if one can believe this! and I have been using TeX for over twenty years!) that I have 
looked at LaTeX3 code (`expl3` to be more precise, I still cannot make myself use LaTeX), I have 
found a number of the same tricks that I have almost been ashamed to
use (I have even picked up a couple of slightly shorter ways of achieving some effects).

**So, after this long introduction, what would be your wish list for a TeX extension that addresses original TeX's
programming inefficiencies, and why, if possible?**

Ideally, this will be a **short list** (5 items or less). Only the **programming** environment should be addressed
(i.e. nothing involving TeX's handling of, say, fonts, other typographic issues, etc. Frank Mittelbach's
paper on the topic treats that area quite well). Note that I enjoy TeX's minimalist philosophy and
macro programming in general (although it feels like I have got wings when I switch to writing embedded 
code in C), so I am looking for an answer more in TeX's spirit rather than 'just use LuaTeX' (I have nothing
agains LuaTeX *per se* it just feels a bit *ad hoc*; I also feel that making programming *too easy* is not a great idea). If the answer is '*e-TeX (or some other extension) already does all of this and here is why e-TeX's choices are better*', please elaborate.

I will start with my own wish list:

`\xxpandafter{tokens}` -- expands the token following the group

`\iftoks{token list}{token list}` -- compares two token lists (same as 
       `\def\listone{...}\def\listtwo{...}\ifx\listone\listtwo ...` but expandable)

`\unlet token` -- expands to a category code, character code token or nothing if the token is not an active 
       character/control sequence let to such a character

`\numexpr` -- same as e-TeX (only wish it was paired with `\endnumexpr` instead of `\relax`)

`\batchxmode{...}` allows for automatic recovery from errors for the code expanded inside the braces,
       itself expands to nothing (i.e. same as `\batchmode ... \errorstopmode` but expands to nothing)

Comment: I think I don't agree with the closing idea; I like this question, especially that I predict that I could learn something from answers posted by Grand TeX Wizards.

Comment: Also, I'm curious, why the OP feels that "making programming too easy is not a great idea".  (I can imagine a sound argument for that, though not necessarily agree with it, but I'd like to hear the OP's opinion.)

Comment: @mbork The reason I think making programming too easy is not a good idea for a highly specialized system such as TeX is such accessibility tends to be abused, in the sense that `quick and dirty' solutions eventually prevail. Think of how much software has been written as shell scripts! This is somewhat subjective of course, I am mainly trying to gather information and to learn something (I have written TeX extensions myself before).

Comment: Maybe the question should be community wiki? It doesn't really fit as a regular question, I don't think, because it isn't really clear what will count as a good answer. (What criteria will the OP use when deciding which answer to accept? It isn't clear.) Also it isn't clear to me how useful it is given that it is focused on commands which do not exist. That's not to say useful stuff won't emerge but it will probably be from disputes about the answers e.g. 'I'd like `\xyz`...' followed by 'But you can use `\abc` for that!' etc.

Comment: I would actually prefer to move it to a community wiki, I just have not found a way to do it other than 'ask the moderators'. Does this comment constitute such a request?

Comment: +1 for CW.  Re: ease of programming: I agree to some extent, but: this already happened anyway with TeX, only not wrt programming but typesetting.  In general: powerful tools *will* be abused (nuclear power plants and nuclear bombs, movable type and bad books, the Web and stupid blogs - it's easy to give more and more examples).  And I'd argue that anything that makes programming easier is (at least potentially) a powerful tool: think how many people like *Mel, a Real Programmer* we (as humanity) might have, and even Java suddenly seems something good...

Comment: Final thought on "quick and dirty hacks": one of my favorites is a saying of my friend (I don't know the original source): "it is built of paper clips and chewing gum".  Astonishingly (I'd even say: frighteningly) many human devices (both social and technological) work like this...

Comment: @mbork Then there is Alan Perlis' _When someone says "I want a programming language in which I need only say what I wish done," give him a lollipop_. I would also like the solution to be unique. I know, I know ...

Comment: Good point.  I guess the distinction may lie somewhere along "make easy things easy and hard things possible" (though I don't like Perl;)).  Some things in programming are hard because they are hard.  Trying to make them easy might be cheating by hiding important things from the would-be programmer.  Some things, however, are hard because you use the wrong tool.  (For instance, I could never understand why I would need the distinctions between expressions and statements and between operators and functions.  In my opinion, they are just annoying complications.)

Comment: There is also an issue of minimalistic aesthetics in TeX. I read through The TeXbook and TeX the program countless times and I have always been amazed at how deliberate Knuth's choices were. I could disagree with some of his motivations but his reasoning was always impeccable. In contrast, it seems that most extensions just solve a `pet problem'. I like the microtypography in pdfTeX but I would not touch pdf documents with a 10 foot pole if I could. And now it is too late.

Comment: Is there a way to move this to a community wiki? I agree with the moderators that this is not the right format for a question and answer forum but I could not find a way to make it into a CW directly. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is a quote by David Kastrup: '_TeX is not a language for quick-and-dirty solutions. There are those things it has been specifically created for, and those tend to be quick-and-easy. That set is limited. Anything else is more in the slow-and-painful department. And sometimes there are shortcuts through the pain. It is like ripping a band-aid off instead of slowly pulling it._' I actually think it is TeX's strength, on top of its stability.

Comment: I just came across this question and all of your requests (apart from `\unlet` which I'm not sure I understand what it's supposed to do) are really easy to implement using LuaTeX. https://termbin.com/pvkq

Comment: Well, thanks for the code but this does not quite do what I proposed: (1) your code leaves `\next`, etc. (re)defined (i.e. it produces side effects) (2) the `\batchxmode` example is not expandable (I just want an analog of `eval` for TeX) (3) worst of all, it uses LuaTeX; I think LuaTeX is wonderful software, do not get me wrong, I just think it takes (has taken, unfortunately) TeX in a terribly misled direction. The reason for `\unlet` is TeX's inability to distinguish between 'true' characters and those that had been 'let' to such. In 256 char TeX this can be done using macros.

Comment: To add to the above, while I can surmise what `\immediate...` primitives do from the examples in the LuaTeX reference manual, there is not a word in it about what they *actually* do! Such is the level of documentation of LuaTeX. Compare that to the masterpiece that is The TeXbook. I would rather deal with TeX macro writing idiosyncrasies than try to follow a moving target like LuaTeX, poorly documented at that.